# Understanding iterables and generators in Python

Tags: python, generator

I recently came across the idea of generators in Python, so I made a basic example for myself:

```
def gen(lim):
    print 'This is a generator'
    for elem in xrange(lim):
        yield elem
    yield 'still generator...'
    print 'done'

x = gen
print x
x = x(10)
print x
print x.next()
print x.next()
```

I was wondering if there was any way to iterate through my variable `x` and have to write out `print x.next()` 11 times to print everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the whole point of using a generator in the first place:

```
for i in x:
    print i
```

```
This is a generator
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
still generator...
done
```

Comment: If I wanted to use the `.next()` method, I would just treat `x` like a list and use `.next()` to iterate through the list?

Comment: @MaxKim Why would you want to use the `.next()` method? You can iterate through a generator using a simple `for`-loop as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can actually just iterate through the generator as if it were a list (or other iterable):

```
x = gen(11)
for i in x:
    print i
```

Calling x.next() is actually not particular to generators — you could do it with a list too if you wanted to. But you don't do it with a list, you use a for loop: same with generators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for loop to iterate generator.

```
def gen(lim):
    print 'This is a generator'
    for elem in xrange(lim):
        yield elem
    yield 'still generator...'
    print 'done'

for x in gen(10):
    print x
```